# Python Syntax Error when making discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

When I try program a simple bot that sends a cookie emoji on the call "!cookie", I am given this error message.

```
RESTART: C:/Users/matth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/InfoBot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:/Users/matth/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/InfoBot.py", line 1, in <module>
import discord
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
from .client import Client, AppInfo, ChannelPermissions
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 38, in <module>
from .state import ConnectionState
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\state.py", line 36, in <module>
from . import utils, compat
  File "C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\compat.py", line 32
create_task = asyncio.async
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "cookie":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, ":cookie:")




client.run("********************************")
```

I'm censoring out my token but I hope that won't interfere with solving the problem. Thanks <3

Comment: Either use an older version of Python or a newer version of discord.py.

Comment: There's no fixed version yet - the fix has been committed but not released.

Answer (score 2):

Your copy of the library lacks this commit:

- [Stop asyncio.async throwing a syntax error in 3.7.](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/commit/1863a1c6636f53592519320a173ec9573c090c0b)

The problem is that Python 3.7 introduced `async` as a keyword, so that `asyncio.async` is no longer valid syntax.